# Does ML.NET support SVM with RBF kernel?

Tags: c#, .net, svm, ml.net

I would like to use ML.NET for a binary classification problem.  In particular, I would like to use an SVM with RBF kernel.  Is it possible to do this using ML.NET, and if so, could you provide an example and/or references?  I cannot find any mention of SVM/RBF in the documentation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest method to RBF I could find in the docs is [Local Deep SVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.trainers.ldsvmtrainer?view=ml-dotnet), based on [this paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v28/jose13.pdf). It seems to be more advanced than RBF, at least more cost-efficient.